# why is only my first div changing colors?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to change each of my div's background color to black when my mouse enters the div using an eventlistener. it currently is only switching the first div to black but not any other div. why is my eventlistener only applying to the first 'contentDivs' div?

example:[image: 1]

this is my html code:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainContainer"></div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

this is my javascript code:

```
for(x=0; x<64; x++) {
    const contentDivs = document.createElement('div');
    contentDivs.id = 'contentDivs';

    document.getElementById('mainContainer').appendChild(contentDivs);
}

document.getElementById('contentDivs').addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    document.getElementById('contentDivs').style.background = 'black';
})
```

this is what shows up when inspecting the elements in google chrome:
[image]

Comment: because IDs are supposed to be unique throughout the entire document.

Comment: [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is meant to find the first element with that ID. The purpose of an ID is to be unique.
If you use class instead you can use `getElementByClassName` to get a list of all the divs, and add the event listener to each

Comment: Also, why not use css `:hover` ?

Comment: If the only purpose of this to colour the div black on mouse entry, then you should be using pure css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select many elements you can use `querySelectorAll`. If you want to select one please use `querySelector`.

I've used minimal changes for your example. Ideally you should take advice of comments and change the identifying method to be class rather than id.

Lastly, I've added another effect using css alone, so you can compare how to make style changes using :hover class.

```js
for (x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
  const contentDivs = document.createElement('div');
  contentDivs.id = 'contentDivs';

  document.getElementById('mainContainer').appendChild(contentDivs);
}

document.querySelectorAll('#contentDivs').forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    elem.style.background = 'black';
  })
})
```

```css
#contentDivs {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: 500ms all;
}

#contentDivs:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainContainer"></div>


</body>
```

Comment: oh, that makes sense. thank you! i'm still a little new to learning javascript but starting to get the hang of it. i did follow everyone's recommendation to change the contentDivs to a class from id though.

i would use css but my project calls for using dom manipulation to change the html elements. it's part of an etch a sketch project.